# Is it possible to block users from leaving their home directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, sftp

I'm creating a webserver, and I will have many users ssh/sftp into it. All they need to do is within their home directory, for example, `/home/user/`.

Many people have told me to use chroot, but it seems like it's a little bit too much, plus I'm going to have multiple users log in into the server so it'll be just a huge load on the server.

So to recap, I want to prevent users from leaving their home directory, `/home/user/`. Is this possible?

Comment: It is with chroot..

Comment: Would you recommend chroot with multiple users on the server?

Answer (score 4):

Why would `chroot` be a "huge load on the server"? This is *precisely* what `chroot` was designed to do. There are guides aplenty on the internets that you can follow to get things set up.

Comment: I read that it can slow down the server and take more memory. Would you recommend it with multiple users ssh/sftp into the server?

Comment: It's likely that things will be just fine. Just give it a try. If it doesn't end up working, nothing has been lost.

Comment: its not a CPU load, but it requires each user to essentially have their own os install in their home directory.  Otherwise an ssh user chrooted to their $HOME directory is pretty much not able to do anything. (like they couldn't run `ls` or `cat` since those require access to /bin and /lib)

Comment: A chroot does not imply a full OS copy. It depends on what you want available to a user once in the chroot. Also, there is no performance penalty or overhead.

Answer (score 1):

SSH has built in chroot features for sftp, with ssh its a bit trickier since the users get to start a fully shell, but its also possible. Check out this howto:
http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny